# How to see if I installed something on root?

Tags: wine, root

I might've did `winecfg` as root and instead of configuring wine in Home i think it is in root folder as well.

How can check it and should I delete it, is it safe to have that there? How to delete it if so

Comment: run `sudo bash -c "ls /root"` to list the directories there!

Comment: `sudo` will elevate your privileges in order to delete, ls etc.  if you don't want to sudo every command, you can `su` to switch user (but remember to switch back with ctrl-d/exit!)

Comment: it's only "desktop" and "release.key" there

Comment: Then your ok it's not there!

Comment: Please make that `sudo bash -c "ls -al /root"` to also any hidden file

Comment: is it ok to delete with `rm` ?

Comment: yes use `sudo rm -rf /root/.wine`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sudo bash -c "ls -al /root"` to list the directories there and yes you should delete it as it's not the appropriate place to have that application.

To delete them do:

```
sudo rm -rf /root/.wine
```

Comment: actually by doing `-al` I see .wine  there and even .minecraft installed by my girlfriend, how can I delete these